# Two triangles have the same Euler line

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC $ a nonequilateral triangle s.t. $tgB\cdot tg C=3$. Let $A'\in BC$ s.t. $AA'\perp BC $ and $B', C'$ are the middles of $AC $ and $AB $ respectively.

Show that the triangles $ABC $ and $A'B'C'$ have the same Euler line.

I think that is something wrong because $A $, the orthocenter of $ABC $ and the orthocenter of $A'B'C'$ are collinear. Therefore this is the Euler line. But then $A'$ is the middle of $BC $. So the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: According to my GeoGebra sketch, the orthocenters coincide, so they don't determine the common Euler line. (The Euler line appears to be parallel to $\overline{BC}$.)